# Нужно чтобы Телеграм бот сохранял видео большего размера на ПК (с которого запущен), есть такой код но он сохраняет пустой файл

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['video'])
async def video_scan_message(msg: types.Message):
    TOKEN = ""
    video_id = msg.video.file_id
    video_info = await bot.get_file(video_id)
    fi = video_info.video_path
    name = msg.video.file_name
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(f'https://api.telegram.org/video/bot{TOKEN}/{fi}',f'./{name}')
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, 'Файл успешно сохранён')
```

Comment: Займитесь отладкой. Во первых, можно проверить код ответа и сам ответ, что возвращает запрос в API Telegram. Также, инерес может представлять содержимое переменных, связаных с видео (`fi`, `name`, ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
video = message.video
await bot.download(video)
```

Подробнее: [Документация](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/download_file.html)